# How to fix HttpErrorResponse 404 Not found Error

Tags: angular

I am getting error message on web console, it says "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup: 404 Not Found". I tried looking for solutions online, but it did not help. How do I fix this issue?

Auth Service Code

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'signin', {
  email, 
  password 
}, httpOptions);



 register(username: string, email: string, password: string, firstname: string, lastname: string, steamhex: string, callsign: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'signup', {
  username,
  email,
  password,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  steamhex,
  callsign,
}, httpOptions);
```

[Node server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTgql.png)

Comment: Do you have an api server set up? If yes, check if its hosted on the correct port

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: ok! 
Can you show the part where you implement the auth api?
Also: its good practice to test out an API Server with an api-test tool like postman (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjgYtQK_zLE). With that you can call and test the API methods before using them in the frontend of you application

Comment: The code where you set up your routes would also be very helpful.

Comment: I got it working I fixed what I was doing wrong.